# How to get attachment details (who uploaded and in which activity) in a workflow in documentum

Tags: java, workflow-activity, documentum

I have created a workflow template having some manual activities. Performers of these activities are groups and any user from these groups can attach some documents to the workflow when they get respective work item in their inbox. Is there any way to differentiate who has attached what document in which activity?

`IDfCollection listAttachment = wf.getAttachments()` provides me all the attachments in the workflow. Is there any way to differentiate which user has attached which document in which activity?

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote DFC code I suppose you want this via code:

```
IDfCollection listAttachment = wf.getAttachments();
while(listAttachment.next()){
    ((IDfWorkflowAttachment)listAttachment).getCreatorName(); // return who has add it 
    ((IDfWorkflowAttachment)listAttachment).getCreationDate(); // return when was added
}
```

Unfortunately you can find out in which activity it was added. 
Check [this link](http://www.nathanobert.com/dfc7/com/documentum/fc/client/IDfWorkflowAttachment.html) for IDfWorkflowAttachment javadocs.